# How to use language files in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

right now I am typing out my messages in the controllers I use like this:

```
TempData["flashError"] = "There Was A Problem Updating Your Account, Please Try Again";
```

I would like to reference a key/value system such as:

```
TempData["flashError"] = Messages["accountProblem"];
```

Is there a certain way to do this so I can maintain my messages from a separate file? Can someone tell me best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html). You'd basically externalize the messages into resource files for each language and then you could use the strongly typed class that is automatically generated by Visual Studio to access those strings in your code.

Answer (score 1):

to add to Darin's answer

there's a sample application that uses **resource files for MUI**

you can **download** it from here: http://prodinner.codeplex.com

it also has a [code walkthrough pdf file](http://prodinner.codeplex.com/releases/view/81382#DownloadId=335681)

also, see it **live**: http://prodinner.aspnetawesome.com

Comment: Thanks I was needing an example.

Comment: Please note that bare links to your own website/product are not encouraged here for two reasons; First, an answer should be posted as a self-contained answer, not a mere link to an external site. Second, self-promotion tends to be frowned upon here, and often is flagged as spam (especially if there is no disclosure that you are linking to your own site/product).